# Deploy SSIS package from file system to SQL server with DTUTIL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cmd, ssis

I'm trying to move an SSIS package from the file system to a remote server.

File system to server:

`& DTUTIL /FILE c:\Temp\TestPackage.dtsx /DestServer server2 /COPY SQL;TestPackage`

And the error:

> TestPackage : The term 'TestPackage' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Here's the Microsoft documentation on DTUTIL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the argument should solve the problem. Try this:

```
& DTUTIL /FILE c:\Temp\TestPackage.dtsx /DestServer server2 /COPY "SQL;TestPackage"
```

You could also escape the semicolon:

```
& DTUTIL /FILE c:\Temp\TestPackage.dtsx /DestServer server2 /COPY SQL`;TestPackage
```

Comment: I guess I should have added, that wasn't the question, but just a possibly related error. "Can I go from one server to another" is the main concern. I appreciate the help with that part though!

Comment: @coinbird Copying a package from one server to another one is definitely supported by  DTUTIL.

Comment: Cool. I shouldn't have posted two questions at once here. I'll change this to deal with the one that you answered, and make a new question for the "one server to another" thing. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I figured it out, `& DTUTIL /SOURCESERVER "server1" /SQL TestPackage /DESTSERVER "server2" /COPY "SQL;TestPackage"`